# Swift record video using same method as taking photo

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm currently using the following code to allow users to take photos:

```
private func configurePhotoView() {
    capturedPhoto.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    capturedPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
    capturedPhoto.hidden = true

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    photoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error: NSError?
    photoDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: photoCaptureDevice, error: &error)

    if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(photoDeviceInput) {
        captureSession!.addInput(photoDeviceInput)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

            captureSession!.startRunning()

            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "focusPhoto:"))
        }
    }
    else {
        //TODO: Handle error
    }

    photoOverlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
}
```

When they press a button this function gets called:

```
@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                var dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                self.capturedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                self.capturedPhoto.image = self.capturedImage
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This code lets me take photos with whatever aspect ratio I desire. Is there a way I can modify the `didPressTakePhoto` code to make a video?

I can't find even one swift tutorial on how to make a custom video recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AVCaptureSession` currently only has one output, which is an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. If you want to capture video, you need to add either an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` or an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` as an output to your capture session.

AV Foundation Programming Guide here: [Still and Video Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html).

Comment: Hi @leekaiinthesky do you happen to know how fix blurriness at the start and end of a video? Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912050/avoiding-blurriness-at-start-end-of-video-even-after-using-setpreferredvideos. Thanks for your time!